# Meaning of ということで?

Tags: grammar

So, I had previously asked about ことで but this time it looks different.

Context :

*Two people are talking, the rich girl says that everyone tries to act as a subtitute parent to her to steal the fortune she inherited from her family, then the person before her says that he considers her as his true grandchild, and that she can count on him. She then answers :*

> 当面はノーサンキューということで。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation 「当面はノーサンキューということで。」 implies "Leave me alone for the time being".
「当面はノーサンキュー**ということで**。」is made from 「当面はご配慮{はいりょ}はノーサンキュー*ということで*お願{ねが}いします。」 which means like 「当面はご配慮は不要{ふよう}**ということで**ご対応{たいおう}願{ねが}いします。」: literally it means "*I ask you to behave under the condition that not any consideration is needed for me for the time being*".

Comment: Can I consider [ということでお​願い] as a "soft" command/request form?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira: I've never thought like that, but if I consider the use of the phrase carefully, yes, it sounds like a "soft" command. Thank you for your discovery!

Comment: So, is ということで a casual way of saying ということでお願ねがいします ?

Comment: @Ushiromiya:  >is ということで a casual way of saying ということでお願がいします ? Yes. It is also used for like ということでよろしく。 or ということでよろしくお願いします。By the way Onegaishimasu is written お願いします, not お願ねがいします.

Comment: Do you have an exemple of a sentence using ということで (besides mine) ? I have a hard time understanding it completely.

Comment: @Ushiromiya: (1) 今日の準備{じゅんび}は終{お}わりました。明日{あす}は朝{あさ}８時{じ}からということで（皆{みな}さんよろしくお願いします）。 (2) 今日{きょう}皆さんにお話{はな}ししたことは聞{き}かなかったということで（よろしくお願いします）。 (3) 会費{かいひ}は一人{ひとり}一万円{いちまんえん}ということで（よろしくお願いします）。

Comment: you should consider putting this sentence as an edit to the original answer, i think whole sentences in the comment session get hard to read and may confuse the reader